# Trigonometric Integrals times exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Let's say I want to evaluate the integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{ax}\cos^{a}(x) \,dx$$
where $1\leq a \leq 5$ .

One standard way to go around would be by applying parts. That would result of course in many operations (sure I would get lost) unless $a=1$. Now I tried a method however I don't get any result by doing the following:

I re-wrote the $\cos^a$ as a complex form , then I expanded it using the binomial expansion and then I tried to integrate term by term. Problem being that the desired result , whatever that is, won't come out. Using this method I get an approximated result.

Is there a better/smarter way to integrate it? Just to be more specific , let's say I want to integrate $ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{2x}\cos^2(x) \,dx $.

P.S: The limits of integration are random. I'm just looking something in general. I am aware of another technic (it also does not work here) and of contour integration (which always works)

Thanks.

Comment: Is $a$ supposed to be an integer?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $a$ is supposed to be a natural number, that is $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive integer $a$, you can write $\cos(x) = (\exp(ix) + \exp(-ix))/2$ and expand the $a$'th power using the binomial theorem.  You get

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} 2^{-a} \sum_{j=0}^a {a \choose j} \exp((a + i(a-2j)) x) \; dx
= 2^{-a} \sum_{j=0}^a {a \choose j} \left.\dfrac{\exp((a+i(a-2j))x)}{a + i(a-2j)} \right|_{x=0}^{\pi/2}$$
which after some simplification should give you the answer.

EDIT:
In the case $a=2$, you should get 
$$ \dfrac{1}{4} \dfrac{e^{(1+i)\pi} - 1}{2+2i} + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{e^\pi - 1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4} \dfrac{e^{(1-i)\pi} - 1}{2-2i} = \dfrac{e^\pi-3}{8}$$

Comment: Ok, I ran this for the specific case I mentioned above, but there was no result.